# How do i redirect and pass multiple variables with php, when i do it with header, the page just reloads?

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass multiple variables from a form to another page where there will be final data procesing, how do i pass them after the submit button is pressed?

````php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $date=$_POST['date'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $people=$_POST['people'];


    header('location:'.SITEURL.'make-a-reservation.php?name='.$name.'email='.$email.'&date='.$date.'&phone='.$phone.'&email='.$email.'&people='.$people);
}```
````

Comment: Why don't you just submit the form directly to the make-a-reservation script? That would be simpler

Comment: at the make a resertvation you choose the time, avaliable times are displayed by the chosen date

Comment: How is that relevant? Your script above just receives some data and sends that exact same data to another page. All I'm saying is, just send the data directly there instead of via the code you've shown us

Comment: @ADyson Never mind, i've figured out why it was not sending the header, i've been echoing values in the actual form to disable dates. Going to do the other stuff in js now

Comment: @fie you have no idea whether the parameters are being passed to this script via post or get. The header command of course sends then via get but that's going to another script, and again we don't know whether the code there tries to read from get or post, because we can't see that code. Also we have no idea whether it's "hackable" (or what risks you are considering under that rather broad banner) because as yet the data is not being used for anything except passing it to another script...that in itself is not a risk.